# How to create a catch all https "default_server" for "Welcome to Nginx!" Page, using self signed certificate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, https, defaults

I am running a LEMP server with Nginx, and have the "`listen 80 default_server;`" directive enabled for port 80 in the catch all `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` directive. When I browse to the url: http://my.servers.ip.address, the server automatically redirects to a page that says

> Welcome to nginx! If you see this page, the nginx web server is
> successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
> Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
> Thank you for using nginx.

However, in my default.conf file, I only have '`default_server`' enabled for port 80, because I don't have a https certificate for my servers IP address.

So, When I go to https://my.servers.ip.address, instead of Nginx directing me toward a secure version of the default Nginx Welcome page, it directs me to my first valid virtual hosts https address, giving me a

> Connection Is Not Private This website may be impersonating
> "my.servers.ip.address" to steal your personal of financial
> information. you should go back to the previous page.
> notice first.

What I would like Nginx to do is have a "default_server" option in Nginx's default.conf for "`listen 443 default_server`;" directive, so that when I go to https://my.server.ip.address in a web browser, it goes to a self signed secure version of the default "Welcome to Nginx!" page, instead of one of my virtual host's domains.

So my question is, how do I implement a catch all "default_server" in /etc/conf.d/default.conf for https, using self signed certificates, instead of default.conf redirecting to the https address of my first virtual host?

Below is my /etc/nginx/default.conf file.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  root /var/www/html/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  }

 # A long browser cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
       access_log        off;
       log_not_found     off;
       expires           360d;
  }

  # disable access to hidden files
  location ~ /\.ht {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      deny all;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add `listen 443 ssl default_server;` to the above configuration, together with `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives pointing to any valid certificate (self-signed or otherwise).

Comment: So my Server block would look like this?                                                           "server {
  listen 80 default_server; listen 443 ssl default_server;"